# How does ipython modify the imp module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, python-import

After executing these commands in the terminal:

```
mkdir /tmp/pymodule
touch /tmp/pymodule/__init__.py
```

the following script gives me an `ImportError` when run with Python 2.7.12:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import imp
print(imp.find_module('/tmp/pymodule'))
```

which is reasonable because `/tmp/pymodule` is not on my Python path. However, if I use `%run` to run the script in `ipython` (version 5.1.0), I get `(None, '/tmp/pymodule', ('', '', 5))`. Interestingly, if I run the same script with Python 3.5.2, I also get `(None, '/tmp/pymodule', ('', '', 5))`.

Why is this happening in ipython on Python 2? My guess is that `ipython` is overriding the builtin `imp` module for Python 2/Python 3 compatibility.

I found this behavior because I was using `pkgutil.find_loader()` to test if strings were modules on the Python path or were directory paths. `pkgutil.find_loader()` calls `imp.find_module()`. My test works in a plain script but does not work for directory paths with `__init__.py` files inside of `ipython`. In Python 3, `pkgutil.find_loader()` handles these paths the same as in Python 2 despite the fact that `imp.find_module()` behaves differently (probably because it doesn't use `imp` any more since it has been deprecated).

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue - same behavior for python2 and ipython (2) with an `ImportError`.  And same behaviour for python3 and ipython (3) with no error.  So, which version of python is used by your ipython session?

Comment: ipython (v. 5.1.0) is using Python 2.7.12. Actually, I am using version 4.2.0 of the Anaconda distribution. Unless I have overlooked something in my environment, it should be a vanilla version of Anaconda (no extra packages or configuration).

Comment: I just tried on another machine running Arch Linux with the `python`, `python2`, `ipython`, and `ipython2` packages from the official repos and I see the same behavior.